# Why EF Core is generating the wrong name of the navigation field when creating SELECT clause causing exception?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a asp.net core 2.2. project with EF Core. I'm facing this issue. Look at the table below that has two foreign keys:

[image]

When I run scaffolding, the above table called RubrosContablesCtasBanc, EF created the class and Fluent DbContext as it follows:

```
public partial class RubrosContablesCtasBanc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCuentaBancaria { get; set; }
    public int IdRubroContable { get; set; }

    public virtual CuentasBancarias IdCuentaBancariaNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual RubrosContables IdRubroContableNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

in the OnModelCreating of DbContext:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<RubrosContablesCtasBanc>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdCuentaBancariaNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.RubrosContablesCtasBanc)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdCuentaBancaria)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_RContablesCtaBanc_CuentasBancarias");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdRubroContableNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.RubrosContablesCtasBanc)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdRubroContable)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_RContablesCtaBanc_RubrosContables");
        });
```

However, when I run a query it generates an error due to the fields that are part of the relationship:

```
SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[IdCuentaBancaria], [r].[IdCuentaBancariaNavigationId], [r].[IdRubroContable], [r].[IdRubroContableNavigationId]
FROM [RubrosContablesCtasBanc] AS [r]"
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'IdCuentaBancariaNavigationId'.
Invalid column name 'IdRubroContableNavigationId'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:808591b0-9ee9-4f35-92d0-e962d48184fa
```

I don't understand how EF is creating the query to put wrong field names adding the Id at the end of the navigation fields.

**Updated**:
I want to make clear that this is not happening in other situations, for example, I have another class entity created by scaffolding:

[image]

however, queries are working fine:

[image]

As you can see above, the navigation property IdPersonaNavigation is loading its data. Like this, many others work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties with `NavigationId` suffix, I think, come from [EF core conventions](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions#primary-key).

Maybe there is bug in EF core or EF core generator somewhere caused by `Id` in prefix. As workaround try [`ForeignKeyAttribute`](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute), for example:

```
public partial class RubrosContablesCtasBanc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCuentaBancaria { get; set; }
    public int IdRubroContable { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdCuentaBancaria")]
    public virtual CuentasBancarias IdCuentaBancariaNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdRubroContable")]
    public virtual RubrosContables IdRubroContableNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, check the updated post, I have another similar situations that work fine, no errors caused by the wrong conventions applied. I have another question: If I use the conventions, how can I do with a table Person that has two fields that relates with same table (Users - PK: Id) because refers to user created and user removed, so, will I have to named them UserId and UserId which is not possible in the same table? Can I name those fields in a better way like UserCreatedId and UserRemovedId??